# Compiling latex file which depends on several file with ninja build system

Tags: latex, ninja

I want to compile this file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\include{one.tex}
\include{two.tex}
\end{document}
```

which it's named `src.tex`.

I want to compile with `pdflatex` with [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)

```
rule cc
  command = pdflatex $in
  description = Compile with pdflatex


build src.pdf: cc src.tex
```

but I want to specify that `src.pdf` depends, also, on `one.tex` and `two.tex`.

How to do it?

I have to put `| one.tex two.tex` or `|| one.tex two.tex` at the end of `build` line?